# How to create input into Select Option in html not provided as an option?

Tags: javascript, html

Is creating an input other than the 4 options possible from client side? ofcourse the normal client interface does not provide for it.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I am designing a web app. Is creating an input which is not an option, possible? if yes, I will have to provide validation logic at the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The public interface of your application is your HTTP server, not your webpage. Arbitrary data can always be sent to it.

Comment: For example, anyone could create an HTML document containing a modified copy of the form. Or, simpler, use Firebug in Firefox to edit the HTML code of the application (it would suffice to just change the `value` attribute of an `option` element to whatever you want to send), then submit the form.